# Getting 504 on AJAX call [MVC]

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, model-view-controller

I am encountering a 504 gateway_timeout on a certain page of my site when it is hosted in our production site's IIS. It works fine on my localhost, on our test site, and on our production server's localhost (accessed via localhost/link/abc)

I have ran out of ideas why this was occcurring, here is my code below:

```
function GetTableData(date, period, offset, method) {
    $(".load-bar").show();
    updateTimeStampTabular(date, period, offset, "Try");
    var link;

        if (method != "aa"  && method !=     "bb" && method != "cc") 
        {
        link = "../Tabular/";
         }
        else {
        link = "../Statistics/";
        }

        $.ajax({
        url: link + method,
        type: "GET",
        timeout: 200000,
        data: {
            date: date,
            period: period,
            timezoneOffset: offset
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(".statistics .table-responsive").html(data);
            var overallStatusText = $(".right-sidebar span.status");
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(textStatus);
        alert(xhr.statusText);
        if (globalVars.unloaded)
            return;
        }
        });
        }
```

I can confirm that a function with "dd" exists in my TabularController and it uses [HttpGet] annotation. Any thoughts why this is happening when accessing the prod url? Other methods are called through the same way and they work fine, except for this instance on Tabular/Getdd

Comment: Most of the time, a 504 Gateway Timeout error means that whatever other server is taking so long that it's "timing out" is probably down or not working properly.

Since this error is usually a network error between servers on the Internet, or an issue with an actual server, the problem probably is not with your computer, device, or Internet connection.

Comment: Can you access the link through Postman? That's an easy way to see if the problem is your code or a machine/network issue.

Comment: @JeffSiver yeah I can access the link, i am doing an ajax call to update vaules of a PartialView and tht's where the gateway_timeout error occurs

Comment: @PranavPatel it is also us who host it on our server via IIS. Could there be an error with the way we published our website?

Comment: first do one simple thing, check your url with parameter using any rest client   that is it responding properly or not

Comment: @PranavPatel It returned the gateway_timeout after exactly 60 seconds

Comment: @PranavPatel on our test server, i used DHC to access and it returned '302 found', on our prod server however, it returns 504 gateway_timeout after 1 minute

Comment: If i use the real url (IP), it returns something. If i use the siteUrl (words), it causes the error

Comment: I think you haven't indicated datatype for get request also try to use JSON.Stringify for your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this had something to do with the timeouts set with AWS. 
To fix this issue, we adjusted the timeout settings and increased the limit of the waiting time of requests. My query (joining 2 very large and busy tables) sometimes yield results after 3 mins, so we just increased the limit to higher than 3mins.

I noticed that this is the cause because there are no issues with long waiting time if I view it with the test website and the issue only happens with the live website which uses a site certificate.

If I could go back to this issue however, I think i'd redo the query and make it work faster (if possible)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I was facing these problem and, indeed, the cloud provider can overwrite some configurations. In my case, it was set on the LoadBalancer settings, to cut the connection after exactly 60 seconds .
It was replacing (or ignoring) all IIS or application settings.
I hope this information may help others in the future.